# JavaScript and AJAX - IDE

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have knowledge of JavaScript and had enough experience, kind of planning to step into AJAX.

I am looking for an IDE in which I can learn AJAX. Furthermore, and are there any plug-ins for NetBeans for AJAX with Inellisense.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/(S(vovsvx454o5rex452c4ypcy3))/ajax/

Answer (score 6):

AJAX isn't a new language, it's a concept of using JavaScript to communicate with a server-side language. Therefore, the tools you use for writing JavaScript and whatever Server-side code you use will be good for AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.org/studio) provides an IDE for JavaScript based on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You do not require different IDE to learn AJAX. It is a part of JavaScript so you can use same IDE as that you were using for JavaScript. [Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) offers a very good IDE.